# Stored procedure in adf

Tags: azure, factory

I have 10 stored procedure with parameters I want to run within a single stored procedure is it possible if yes how to do it if no can I do it with other activity

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need three activities. A lookup activity to get the names of your stored procedures. A ForEach activity to loop over all of your stored procedures in Azure Data Factory. Inside the ForEach activity, you will only have one StoredProcedure activity.

Comment: So what about the parameters like pipeline id,pipeline name ,pipeline execution time how to capture it..?

Comment: There are system variables supported by Azure Data Factory that you can use. link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables#pipeline-scope

Comment: For example my stored procedure look like

Comment: For example           CREATE PROC usp_dim_Student(pipeline name Varchar 50, createdon datetime, pipelinename varchar(50), updatedon datetime as begin merge(stored procedure)end using stored procedure activity I can import parameters and place system variable in it . If I use lookup activity how to import parameters for all 10 stored procedure and put that in my tables column

Comment: Use the Foreach activity as suggested